# Send existing log file to graylog?

Tags: graylog, gelf

Is there any way that I can send a bunch of existing log files (json content) to graylog? I found few posts googling, but all deal with sending live data to graylog, and unable to find any instructions on how to send existing log file

Answer (score 3):

There are various options for sending existing log messages (text files) to Graylog.

The most basic option to send line-delimited log messages (i. e. not multiline) would be to create a **Raw/Plaintext TCP** input and send the complete file using something like **netcat** (`nc`, `netcat`, `ncat`, `socat`, etc.).

```
# Raw/Plaintext TCP on port 5555/tcp
$ nc graylog.example.org 5555 < /path/to/file
```

If you like it a bit more fancy (with some preprocessing of the log file and buffering of log messages), you could create a **Beats** input and use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) to send the file.